# How to use the localeStorage so that the language doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I need to add the language that will be chosen by somebody to localStorage. After a restart, the page there will be shown in this language, not the default.

When I click on the button it writes to localStorage, but it doesn't work. I can't find decision for this.

```js
let arrLang = {
  'ru': {
    'home-caption-p1': 'Комфортная температура помещения с',
    'home-caption-color': 'экономией до 40%',
    'home-caption-p2': 'за отопительные счета.',
  },
  'en': {
    'home-caption-p1': 'Comfortable room temperature with',
    'home-caption-color': 'savings of up to 40%',
    'home-caption-p2': 'for heating bills.',
  },
  'ro': {
    'home-caption-p1': 'Temperatura confortabilă a camerei cu',
    'home-caption-color': 'economii de până la 40%',
    'home-caption-p2': 'pentru facturile de încălzire.',
  }
};

// Multi-language changes
$(function() {
  $('.translate').click(function() {
    let lang = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.lang').each(function() {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });
    localStorage.setItem('lang', arrLang[lang]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns d-flex">
  <button class="btn translate" id="ru" href="#about">ru</button>
  <button class="btn translate" id="en">en</button>
  <button class="btn translate" id="ro">ro</button>
</div>
<h3 class="lang">
  <span class="lang" key="home-caption-p1">Comfortable room temperature with</span>
  <span class="lang color" key="home-caption-color">savings of up to 40%</span>
  <span class="lang" key="home-caption-p2">for heating bills.</span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the value in localStorage, but you never read it back out again. For this to work as you describe you need to use `getItem()` to check the language, if one was set, and display it.

```
function translate(language) {
  $('.lang').each(function() {
    $(this).text(arrLang[language][$(this).data('key')]);
  });
}

jQuery(function($) {
  // translate the page onload if a language was previously selected 
  var language = localStorage.getItem('lang');
  if (language)
    translate(language);

  // translate the page when a language is clicked
  $('.translate').click(function() {
    let lang = $(this).attr('id');
    translate(lang);
    localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
  });
});
```

Also note that I changed `key` to `data-key` as the former is not a valid attribute of a `span` element.

Comment: You're right, you also needed to change the value you store in localStorage to the key of the object, not the object itself. I've updated the answer, and here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/46y1sawv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are never fetching the stored language from the localstorage while refreashing the page.

I have made some changes in the code to load the default language, please review Might be it helpful for you.

```
let arrLang = { 

'ru': {
    'home-caption-p1': 'Комфортная температура помещения с',
    'home-caption-color': 'экономией до 40%',
    'home-caption-p2': 'за отопительные счета.',
  },
  'en': {
    'home-caption-p1': 'Comfortable room temperature with',
    'home-caption-color': 'savings of up to 40%',
    'home-caption-p2': 'for heating bills.',
  },
  'ro': {
    'home-caption-p1': 'Temperatura confortabilă a camerei cu',
    'home-caption-color': 'economii de până la 40%',
    'home-caption-p2': 'pentru facturile de încălzire.',
  }
};

// Multi-language changes
  let lang = 'en';;
$(function() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('lang'))
  {
    lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')
    loadLangage();
  }
  $('.translate').click(function() {
    lang = $(this).attr('id');

    loadLangage();
    localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
  });
});
  function loadLangage(){
    $('.lang').each(function() {
      if(arrLang[lang] == undefined)
        lang = 'en';
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });
  }
```